# How do I troubleshoot errors in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get a Rails app working on my web host.  Using CPanel, I can create a rails app and I can access the index.html (Welcome aboard) page from my browser.  But when I click on "About your application’s environment", it says "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

I don't have access to any files on the webserver outside of my home directory.  The logs directory under my apps root has a mongrel.log file, and development/production/server/test.log files in it.  I can see the mongrel.log has some info written to it when I start the app server, but none of the other files ever get written to.

I'm not sure if this is an issue with my code, or with the web host, so I don't know whether I should submit a support ticket or not.

Any idea what is wrong or what I need to do to troubleshoot the problem?

Comment: Can you paste error details in logs/production.log

Comment: It is empty, only mongrel.log is ever written to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are just testing the app currently and to get more debug information try to run the app in development mode and make sure that you have `config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local = true` in your environments/development.rb file.

Though I can guess that you might be getting this error because you haven't created your database according your config/database.yml file.

Comment: I think you are right.  Setting to development mode gave me some info in the debug log because of a database issue.  I'll look into this a bet more, but I think that helps a lot.